# C# Invoke progressBar thread for update

Tags: c#, thread-safety, progress-bar, invoke

inside my C# app I define and launch a process like this:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "Resources/";
        startInfo.FileName = "batch.exe";
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.Arguments = "-h usb -o read";

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.CancelOutputRead();
        process.Close();
```

I'm using the DataReceivedEvent for this process to save its output:

```
void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != String.Empty && e.Data != null)
        {
            //Save data 
            result.Add(e.Data);

            if (progressbar.InvokeRequired)
                progressbar.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    progressbar.PerformStep();
                }));
            else
                progressbar.PerformStep();
        }
    }
```

At the same time, each time the DataReceived event fires I would like to update a progressbar. I don't know what is wrong with the code that invokes the progressbar but the thread never get's processed and worse the app locks when it reaches that part of code without throwing any error(while debugging in Visual Studio). Any ideas on how I could make this right? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main thread is stuck on the synchronous process.WaitForExit() call - typical deadlock. process_OutputDataReceived runs in another thread, but Invoke doesn't return - main thread is blocked by WaitForExit.

Remove synchronous WaitForExit call, subscribe to Process.Exited Event and make all cleanup work there.

Comment: Thanks! now it works even with the initial Invoke method I used.

Comment: In any case, BeginInvoke is better and should always be default choice, unless synchronous call is required.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @Alex Farber